# Equivalence of Minimization Problems Involving a Kernel

Tags: statistics, optimization, machine-learning

Let $f(x) =  \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_ik(x,x_i) + \alpha_0$ for some kernel $k$.  I want to show that there exists a kernel such that the solutions to the following optimization problems are the same:

$$\text{min}_{\alpha, \alpha_0} \sum_{i=1}^n[1-y_if(x_i)]_+ + \frac{\lambda}{2}\alpha^TK\alpha $$

and

$$\text{min}_{\alpha, \alpha_0} \sum_{i=1}^n[1-y_if(x_i)]_+ + \frac{\lambda}{2}\alpha^T\alpha $$

where $K_{ij} = k(x_i, x_j)$ and $\alpha = (\alpha_1, ..., \alpha_n)^T$ and $\lambda > 0$.  This is problem 12.2 of *Elements of Statistical Learning* by Tibshirani et. al.  I have zero ideas of where to start.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure this is the point of the question but what if you take $ K $ as the identity matrix: $ K = I $?

Comment: Ex. 12.2 of ESL reads as follows: Show that the solution to (12.29) is the same as the solution to (12.25) for a particular kernel.

where (12.29) is 
$$
\underset{\beta_0, \alpha}{\min}\sum_{i=1}^n (1 - y_i f(x_i))_{+} + \frac{\lambda}{2} \alpha^T \mathbf{K} \alpha
$$
where $\mathbf{K}$ is matrix of kernel evaluation between $x_i, x_j$ and $f$ is 
$$
f(x) = \beta_0 + \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i K(x, x_i)
$$
and (12.25) is
$$
\underset{\beta_0, \beta}{\min}\sum_{i=1}^n (1 - y_i f(x_i))_{+} + \frac{\lambda}{2} \lVert \beta \rVert_2
$$
where $f$ is 
$$
f(x) = h(x)^T \beta + \beta_0
$$